# Why is a migration failing in production but not in development?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.1, migration

Migration fails in production, but ran as expected in development.

```
...                                                               # everything to
20120709174326_add_subject_to_campaigns.rb                        # here runs fine.
20120711001125_set_default_value_for_publishable_in_newsletter.rb # <- this fails.
20120711010818_set_default_value_for_publishable_in_contents.rb
20120711010855_set_default_value_for_published_in_editions.rb
20120711191427_add_newsletter_date_to_newsletters.rb
20120711194230_rename_cm_campaign_sent_at_in_campaigns.rb
```

The migration error looks like this:

```
-bash> heroku run rake db:migrate --remote staging
Running rake db:migrate attached to terminal... up, run.1
==  SetDefaultValueForPublishableInNewsletter: migrating ======================
-- change_column(:newsletters, :publishable, :boolean, {:default=>false})
   -> 0.1554s
rake aborted!
An error has occurred, this and all later migrations canceled:

undefined method `newsletter_date' for #<Newsletter:0x00000005961bd0>
```

The thing is, newsletter_date is not added till later, so why is it failing / mentioning it so soon? It ran perfectly fine in development.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It turns out that the failing migration (`20120711001125_set_default_value_for_publishable_in_newsletter.rb`) ...

```
def up
  change_column :newsletters, :publishable, :boolean, default: false
  Newsletter.scoped.where('publishable is NULL').each do |n|
    n.publishable = false
    n.save
  end
end
```

... [uses the model](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/migrations.html#using-models-in-your-migrations) `Newsletter`, and runs validations before saving (specifically, the `presence` validation on `newsletter_date`) ...

```
validates :newsletter_date, presence: true
```

... but `newsletter_date` does not exist yet, because it (the `newsletter_date` column) is not added till later (`20120711191427_add_newsletter_date_to_newsletters.rb` -- the second-last migration in the list above):

```
class AddNewsletterDateToNewsletters < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    add_column :newsletters, :newsletter_date, :date
  end
end
```

The solution is: (1) in development, **rollback** the migrations to the one before the failing one; (2) **rename** the migration that adds the column, changing its timestamp to just prior to the failing migration; (3) **run** the migrations; (4) **update** git; (5) **push** to Heroku; (6) in production, **run** the migrations; (7) **restart** the Heroku processes.

```
bundle exec rake db:rollback # five times in this case
mv db/migrate/20120711191427_add_newsletter_date_to_newsletters.rb db/migrate/20120711001025_add_newsletter_date_to_newsletters.rb
bundle exec rake db:migrate
git add db/migrate/20120711001025_add_newsletter_date_to_newsletters.rb
git rm db/migrate/20120711191427_add_newsletter_date_to_newsletters.rb
git commit -m "changed migration timestamp to fix migration order issue"
git push staging master
heroku run rake db:migrate --remote staging
heroku restart --remote staging
```

The reason it worked in development is because at the time the migration that set the default value for the `publishable` column in the `newsletters` table ran, the `newsletter_date` column and model validation did not yet exist, so it was not a problem. By the time it all went out to production, the more recent code brought the `newsletter_date` method and related validation into existence, but since migrations run on existing code in order of timestamps, newer code may exist than the database is prepared for.

Comment: To avoid this problem in the future, your continuous integration should be running your migrations from scratch (because that's what your production environment will be doing).

Comment: Oh my. That makes so much sense!